# Android: How to make textview visible with padding

Tags: android, xml, drawable

I want to create this and I have used drawable along with textview in it:

[image]

But I am not getting the textview in center nor whole text is visible due to padding. How do I make changes to my existing code to look like this. For now I don't want the image and just the text and buttons.

rounded_edge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >


        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>

        <stroke android:width="5dp"
            android:color="#000000"/>


        <!--<padding android:left="30dp"
            android:top="350dp"
            android:right="250dp"
            android:bottom="10dp"/>-->

        <gradient android:startColor="#D2E0E2" android:endColor="#D2E0E2"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>

    </shape>
```

yelp_biz_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="350dp"
        android:paddingRight="250dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
        android:textAlignment="center"

        android:gravity="center"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Solution is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
        >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        />


</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I could solve this by adding a linear layout inside another linear layout and it solved the problem.

Comment: Could you please answer below and mark it as accepted instead of editing the question? Thanks?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean 35dp instead of 350dp in `android:paddingTop="350dp"` and 25dp instead of 250dp in `android:paddingRight="250dp"` in `yelp_biz_detail.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

rounded_edge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="16dp"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:top="16dp" />

</shape>
```

yelp_biz_detail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:padding="32dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Your text..." />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_one"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button One" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_two"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button Two" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```